# Create keystore from rsa file

Tags: java, android, xamarin, keytool

I've developed an app who run on 100 devices. Want to update it but if I install the new APK give me error. "**Android App Not Install**. An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed".

I researched and found the problem. 
I changed my **SSD** and that's why my debug.keystore file is gone at formatting.

I have found the **RSA** file in APK. **Can I change my new debug.keystore with the value in the old APK?**

I researched keytool. Can i use **importcert** and give two certificate in one **debug.keystore**?

Comment: if you lost your keystore there is no chance to recover it.

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII but i have the MD5, SHA1, SHA256 values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It that will be possible, everyone can unpack APK and get your private key. Next time do backups before formatting!

I think Google explain it in documentation pretty well

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#secure-key

> Maintaining the security of your private key is of critical
>   importance, both to you and to the user. If you allow someone to use
>   your key, or if you leave your keystore and passwords in an unsecured
>   location such that a third-party could find and use them, your
>   authoring identity and the trust of the user are compromised.
>
> If a third party should manage to take your key without your knowledge
>   or permission, that person could sign and distribute apps that
>   maliciously replace your authentic apps or corrupt them. Such a person
>   could also sign and distribute apps under your identity that attack
>   other apps or the system itself, or corrupt or steal user data.
>
> Your private key is required for signing all future versions of your
>   app. If you lose or misplace your key, you will not be able to publish
>   updates to your existing app. You cannot regenerate a previously
>   generated key.
>
> Your reputation as a developer entity depends on your securing your
>   private key properly, at all times, until the key is expired. Here are
>   some tips for keeping your key secure:
>
> - Select strong passwords for the keystore and key.
> - Do not give or lend anyone your private key, and do not let unauthorized persons know your keystore and key passwords.
> - Keep the keystore file containing your private key in a safe, secure place.
>
> In general, if you follow common-sense precautions when generating,
>   using, and storing your key, it will remain secure.

MD5, SHA1, SHA256 - different digests ( result of [hash-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) ) and cannot be used to restore your keystore.